# Problem with selectors in if statement using len() and operators

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run a section of code with a bunch of "selection criteria" but I've run into a wall.

This is the code:

```
phone= int(input("Enter phone number : "))
if len(str(phone)) != 10 or str(phone)[:2] != "04":
    print("Invalid format. Try again.")
else:
    print("Thanks queen!")
```

However, no matter what input, the output is always

```
Invalid format. Try again.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `str(int("04"))` would strip the leading 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the name, phone numbers are not numbers, they're identifiers (sometimes with superfluous formatting). Your initial conversion of the input to integer is the root of your subsequent problems. The conversion from integer back to string would never result in a leading zero so `str(phone)[:2] != "04"` will always evaluate to `True`.

Without the conversions it's cleaner and correct:

```
phone = input("Enter phone number : ")
if len(phone) != 10 or phone[:2] != "04":
    print("Invalid format. Try again.")
else:
    print("Thanks queen!")
```

You may want to clean the entered phone number directly after input to remove formatting characters:

```
phone = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, phone))
```

Comment: Yeah, I probably went overboard with the conversions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, converting "04" to a string throws a leading zero error. I tried it with converting an int with a non-leading zero and passed the condition to receive, "Thanks queen!"

```
phone = str(3214567890)
firstTwo = phone[:2]
expectedLen = 10
expectedFirstTwo = "32"
if len(phone) != expectedLen or firstTwo != expectedFirstTwo:
    print("Invalid format. Try again.")
else:
    print("Thanks queen!")
```

Comment: There will be no "leading zero error" with the OP's code as written. `int('04')` is not a problem nor is `str(4)` a problem.  `str(04)` is a SyntaxError because `04` is a SyntaxError, but that's not what's happening here.